# UITableView not updating when switching between tabs

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, core-data, swift2

**Preface:** I've tried adding `tableView.reloadData()` to `viewWillAppear` (...and `viewDidLoad`, `viewDidAppear`, etc.) of the `UITableViewController` that's not updating. I threw in `setNeedsDisplay` for S's & G's, too.

I have a `UITabBarController` with 3 tabs on it. Each tab is a `TableViewController` is backed by Core Data and is populated with `NSManagedObjects` from one `NSManagedObjectContext`.

In `TableViewController1` I make changes to the cells, the `tableView` reloads properly and reflects the changes. If I click the tab for `TableViewController2`, the changes made on `TVC1` aren't reflected.

The changes made on `TVC1` are persisting between launches, as I see them on `TVC2` when I close the app and relaunch it.

What am I missing? Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

**Update**

Here's the code in question:

```
func markFavorite(sender: AnyObject) {
    // Store the sender in case you need it later. Might not need this.
    clickedFavoriteButton = sender as! UIButton

    if resultsSearchController.active {
        let indexPath = sender.tag
        let selectedSound = self.filteredSounds[indexPath]
        print("markFavorite's sender tag is \(indexPath)")
        if selectedSound.favorite == 1 {
            selectedSound.favorite = 0
        } else {
            selectedSound.favorite = 1
        }

        saveManagedObjectContext()

    } else {
        let indexPath = sender.tag
        let selectedSound = self.unfilteredSounds[indexPath]
        print("markFavorite's sender tag is \(indexPath)")
        if selectedSound.favorite == 1 {
            selectedSound.favorite = 0
        } else {
            selectedSound.favorite = 1
        }

        saveManagedObjectContext()
    }
}

func saveManagedObjectContext() {

    if managedObjectContext.hasChanges {
        do {
            try self.managedObjectContext.save()
        } catch {
            // catch error here
        }
    }
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: paste some code so that one can help you if there is mistake in your code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You **should** always use a `NSFetchedResultsController` to display Core Data items in a table view. It comes with delegate methods that update your table as the underlying data changes (even before saving).

To get started, examine the Xcode template (Master-Detail) implementation. Once you get the hang of it you will love it. Everything works pretty much out of the box.

Comment: Thank you. I had been told in the past on smaller projects, you can get away without a `fetchedResultsController`, but that appears to have been bad advice. I'll implement the FRC. I'm certain that will resolve the issue. Thank you for your insight.

Comment: I implemented a `frc`. Everything works except the buttons when `frc` is displaying. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33313674/uitableviewcell-button-tags-return-desired-indexpath-in-uisearchcontroller-not?noredirect=1#comment54426488_33313674

Comment: I answered your other question as well. Using `tag`s to identify cell buttons is not a good approach.

Answer (score 0):

You may have to trigger `context.save()` manually because core-data isn't saving the data right away.

```
let context = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate).managedObjectContext!

runOnMain() {
    do {
        try! self.context.save()
    } catch let error as NSError {
        //Handle any upcoming errors here.
    }
}
```

Its important to run the method on the main thread otherwise you will get an error.

this method should do the job:

```
func runOnMain(block: dispatch_block_t) {
    if NSThread.isMainThread() {
        block()
    }else{
        dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), block)
    }
}
```

Please let me know if this approach worked for you.

Comment: Please don't just toss `fatalError` willy-nilly into your `catch` blocks... don't introduce crashes into perfectly recoverable situations...

Comment: thats why i wrote "Handle the error." :) but to make you happy I edited the code...

Comment: There are ways to write "Handle the error." without introducing a crash.  For example: `// handle the error` or `print("Handle the error: \(error.localizedDescription)")`

Comment: You should **never** use anything other than the `NSManagedObjectContext` API to ensure appropriate access to a context.  That includes GCD to run a block on the main thread.  This causes tons of future bugs.  **Always** use `performBlock` to appropriately synchronize access to a context, even if you know it's a main-queue context.  The only exception that is appropriate is access from a UI element which is known to be running in the main run loop already.

Answer (score -1):

You should not try to reload data at any point in view controller lifecycle. Instead create delegates for each tab bar controller, set them properly and call delegate methods only when something really change in your data source. If you are not familiar with delegation you can learn more about it [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Protocols.html)