# UITableViewCell button tags return desired IndexPath in UISearchController, not FetchedResultsController

Tags: ios, uitableview, core-data, uibutton, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I implemented an `NSFetchedResultsController` on a `UITableView` in a Core Data project in Swift 2.0. Additionally, I have a `UISearchController` implemented. Everything works perfectly with the exception of the behavior I'm encountering on my custom `UITableViewCell` buttons.

When `UISearchController` is active, the `customTableViewCell`'s buttons work as they should. If I click the same button when the `fetchedResultsController` is displaying its results, the method thinks Index 0 is the sender, regardless of which button I click.

```
func playMP3File(sender: AnyObject) {

    if resultsSearchController.active {
        // ** THIS WORKS **
        // get a hold of my song
        // (self.filteredSounds is an Array)
        let soundToPlay = self.filteredSounds[sender.tag]
        // grab an attribute
        let soundFilename = soundToPlay.soundFilename as String
        // feed the attribute to an initializer of another class
        mp3Player = MP3Player(fileName: soundFilename)
        mp3Player.play()
    } else {

        // ** THIS ALWAYS GETS THE OBJECT AT INDEX 0 **
        let soundToPlay = fetchedResultsController.objectAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath(forRow: sender.tag, inSection: (view.superview?.tag)!)) as! Sound
        // OTHER THINGS I'VE TRIED
        // let soundToPlay = fetchedResultsController.objectAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath(forRow: sender.indexPath.row, inSection: (view.superview?.tag)!)) as! Sound
        // let soundToPlay: Sound = fetchedResultsController.objectAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath(index: sender.indexPath.row)) as! Sound
        let soundFilename = soundToPlay.soundFilename as String
        mp3Player = MP3Player(fileName: soundFilename)
        mp3Player.play()
    }
}
```

Here's an abbreviated version of my `cellForRowAtIndexPath` to show I'm setting up the cells' buttons:

```
let customCell: SoundTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("customCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! SoundTableViewCell

if resultsSearchController.active {
    let sound = soundArray[indexPath.row]
    customCell.playButton.tag = indexPath.row
} else {
    let sound = fetchedResultsController.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! Sound
    customCell.playButton.tag = indexPath.row
}

    // add target actions for cells
    customCell.playButton.addTarget(self, action: "playMP3file:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
```

I've tried a few other approaches I've found here, such as translating `CGPoints` to `IndexPaths`, etc. without much luck. Everything that looked promising in the compiler crashed when I clicked the button in the simulator.

Thank you for reading.

**Update**
Installed Xcode 7.1, rebooted, cleaned caches, nuked derived data, did a cold boot.

**Solution**

Tags will get the job done in many cases (such as getting the location in an `Array`) and get lots of votes here, but as I've learned, they don't work all the time. Thank you to Mundi for pointing me towards a more robust solution.

```
// this gets the correct indexPath when resultsSearchController is not active
let button = sender as! UIButton
let view = button.superview
let cell = view?.superview as! SoundTableViewCell
let indexPath: NSIndexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForCell(cell)!
let soundToPlay = fetchedResultsController.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! Sound
```

Comment: Any reason for you net fetching the tag in the same way inside that else?
view.superview?.tag instead of sender.tag. Seems to me that you should always use "sender.tag"

Comment: `let soundToPlay = fetchedResultsController.objectAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath(forRow: sender.tag, inSection: (view.superview?.tag)!)) as! Sound` in `playMP3File ` and `let sound = fetchedResultsController.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! Sound` in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` show the same resuts?

Comment: How many section in the table do you have?

Comment: 1 section in the table. I've tried hard-coding the section at 0. What's really p***ing me off is everything about the cell works properly except the ****ing buttons. I know it's an issue with the tags. I'm not the first person to do this, so I must be the dumbest.

Comment: `let sound = fetchedResultsController.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! Sound` crashes. In `lldb`, if I `po sender` I get `0`. `po indexPath` returns `0`. `po sender.indexPath` returns `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`

Comment: Don't reuse cells(dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier), create a new one each time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I've tried a few other approaches I've found here, such as translating CGPoints to IndexPaths, etc. without much luck.

Translating points is indeed the most robust solution. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15711912/427083) contains the correct code.